# Can't start Mariadb properly?

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, permissions, mariadb

When I run the following command:

```
mysqld --defaults-file=/srv/configs/mariadb/my.cnf
```

I get the as follows:

```
150105 21:05:29 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/srv/dbs/mariadb/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
150105 21:05:52 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.21-70.0 started; log sequence number 1616961
150105 21:05:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
150105 21:05:52 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
150105 21:05:52 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150105 21:05:52 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
150105 21:05:52 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'
150105 21:05:52 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.2-MariaDB-1~trusty-wsrep'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution, wsrep_25.10.r4123
```

At this moment terminal something like hangs and the only Ctrl+Z works by sending this process to background.

Some useful information how looks my custom directory for storing databases. Looks like there are should me some files owned by mysql:mysql:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 dnsmasq systemd-journal    16384 янв.   6 00:05 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 dnsmasq systemd-journal       52 янв.   6 00:05 aria_log_control
drwx------ 2 dnsmasq systemd-journal     4096 янв.   5 23:17 bla
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root                   0 янв.   4 21:51 debian-10.1.flag
-rw-rw---- 1 dnsmasq systemd-journal 12582912 янв.   6 00:10 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 dnsmasq systemd-journal 50331648 янв.   6 00:10 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 dnsmasq systemd-journal 50331648 янв.   4 21:51 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 dnsmasq systemd-journal        0 янв.   5 19:05 multi-master.info
drwxr-xr-x 2 dnsmasq root                4096 янв.   5 19:05 mysql
-rw------- 1 root    root                  14 янв.   5 19:05 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------ 2 dnsmasq systemd-journal     4096 янв.   5 19:05 performance_schema
-rw-rw---- 1 dnsmasq systemd-journal    24576 янв.   6 00:10 tc.log
drwx------ 2 dnsmasq systemd-journal     4096 янв.   5 19:27 testo
```

**What do I wrong?**

Comment: unless your mysql install is running as "dnsmasq":, the ownership of your files is totally wrong.

Comment: I've change everything to mysql:mysql but it doesn't work. I get the same `ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/srv/dbs/mariadb/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds`

Comment: "exlusive use"? Is something else using it already?

Comment: I solve the ERROR message by deleting aria_log.00000001 and aria_log_control. Now it works ok. But still I can't understand why after running: `mysqld --defaults-file=/srv/configs/mariadb/my.cnf` terminal hangs/freeze and scan for stdin. Whatever I do nothing change

Comment: @MarcB, you can suggest this: `delete aria_log.00000001, aria_log_control and make chown of all files to mysql:mysql` and I accept your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggle with a similar issue for a few days. My issue was solved by increasing memory from **512MB** to at least **1GB** (Although your issue doesn't seem to be memory related).
I suggest checking if **SELinux is enabled**. It was for me by default on a new **CentOS 7 server**.

**setting**

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

in this file

```
cat /etc/selinux/config
```

fixed my issue. Hope it helps.